# Как сделать, чтобы длинное слово переносилось внутри контейнера flex?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Собственно вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы длинное слово (заголовок) переносилось внутри контейнера flex

html:

```
<div class="flex_container">
  <h1>Loremipsumdolorsitametconsectetur</h1>
</div>
<div class="noflex_container">
  <h1>Loremipsumdolorsitametconsectetur</h1>
</div>
```

css:

```
.flex_container {
  background-color:yellow;
  display:flex;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.noflex_container {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
h1 {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h1 {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!